# If someone in a same-sex marriage converts to Islam, what do they need to do?

Tags: nikah, conversion, homosexuality

In many places in the world, [same-sex marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-sex_marriage) is becoming legal and recognized.

> Same-sex marriage, also known as gay marriage, is marriage between people of the same sex, either as a secular civil ceremony or in a religious setting.

With this growing trend, it's becoming increasingly possible that someone in a same-sex marriage could convert to Islam.

**Question**: If someone in a same-sex marriage converts to Islam, what do they need to do?

(Or, in other words, what is the roadmap in going from "non-Muslim in same-sex marriage" to "good Muslim"?)

Perhaps getting a (legal) divorce would be required, but this strikes me as unwelcoming and may deter people from accepting Allah in their life (which is of far greater importance).  Islam is also against [severing ties of kinship](http://en.islamway.net/article/11913/no-person-severs-ties-of-kinship-would-enter-paradise).  Converts are generally considered to have their past sins erased, and I'm unsure how this enters the picture.

For those who end up getting a divorce, divorces are not instantaneous, so, for a period of time, the person would be Muslim and in a same-sex marriage.  Then there are matters of [tawba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tawba) (repentance) to consider.  Moreover, this legal marriage would interfere if that person wished to seek an opposite-sex marriage.

(I understand some people have strong opinions on this matter; let's keep this civil please.)

Comment: "Perhaps getting a (legal) divorce would be required, but this strikes me as unwelcoming and may deter people from accepting Allah in their life (which is of far greater importance)." Converts have to stop drinking alcohol, gambling, relying on interest (e.g. mortgages), hugging their lifelong friends of the opposite sex, or running a tattoo parlor. Some say instead of not converting, it is better to convert to Islam and continue living a sinful life - which is clearly a sound position - but the verdict is very clear: gay sex is a major sin, gay marriage invalid in Islam. What is the question?

Comment: Dont mean to be rude here but we should seek knowledge that benefits us somehow.. "O Allah, I seek refuge in You from knowledge which does not benefit." There are all kinds of hypothetical situations we can come up with.  "What if a hermaphrodite married another hermaphrodite?  Who would give dowry to whom?"  Instead we should enrich ourselves through Islam and follow the religious rulings that will bring us closer to Allah.

Comment: @hamobi This isn't a Muslim site, it's a site about Islam. While "don't think about this if you aren't in that situation" may or may not be satisfactory for a Muslim, it does nothing to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

That marriage is not valid according to Islam. So if one or both of them converts to Islam, the first thing they need to do is to break their haram union, and separate from each other immediately and repent to Allah SWT for the past sins. Allah is all forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

Friendships are encouraged between humans no matter what their religion is, expect if that person is wicked. (Even if it weren't about religion, distancing yourself from a destructive person is a smart life decision.)

But to come back to your question, I think that the first step for this person to take would be to stop engaging sexually with his partner.

The next step would be to learn more about Islam.

The steps after that are going to be revealed to that person, between himself and Allah.